# Blank Asp.net MVC template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way I can get a blank MVC template for VS2008? Like the only that comes with MVC is nice to see what MVC is all about but it gets annoying when you want to make your own site and you first have to delete all the crap they generated for you.

Like I want to use my own authentication stuff since I understand what is going on and my own style sheets and stuff.

So I have to do through and delete everything ever single time so I wondering does anyone know of a template I can get that just has the basic structure of mvc and the bare minimum of stuff needed in the web.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any currently available, but at the least you can create the template you want by creating a custom [**Visual Studio Template**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx).

**Essentially, after deleting all of the files you don't want, do a File | Export Template in Visual Studio, follow the wizard to the promised land.**

If you end up doing that, I am sure others would love to have it. I have just been too lazy to do it myself, and haven't really been creating a lot of new MVC projects, just working on the same one for months. :)

---

UPDATE: To respond to your comment: Although I haven't really looked too deeply into it, I don't know why you wouldn't be able to include in your project template access to the test project wizard. I cracked open the default ASP.NET MVC project template metadata file and found this near the bottom:

```
<WizardExtension>
   <Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</Assembly>
   <FullClassName>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

If they can do it, I don't know why you wouldn't be able to as well. I am interested in looking into this more, but at the moment I am heading to bed - I am already up WAY too late considering I have a horrible chest cold. :)

Comment: Ya I read about exporting it. The thing is the web.config file I don't know too much about it so its hard to figure out what to delete and not to delete. Some stuff I know off the bat and some I just don't know at all.

Plus I noticed with making your own template you lose the ability to automatically generate the Test Project with it.

Is there a way have one built in with the template?

Comment: Ok well I will try to do some digging too but I am not sure what this template metadata file is.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/740022.aspx) is the way you can create your own template. I'm quite sure there exists one already somewhere, but if it's not - just bake your own. Shouldn't be so hard.