# How to add a custom project template in new Asp.Net MVC 3 project dialog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing a plugin based application using MEF and Asp.NET MVC 3 and I want to create a custom project template to give third party developers when creating new plugins for application.

I can easily export it as a project template but since the host is developed in ASP.NET MVC 3, It seems more logical to be inside new Asp.Net MVC 3 project dialog.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging and 'reflecting', I got a template to successfully show up in the dialog.  Most of the credit goes to this post: [Add custom viewengine to New project dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153016/net-mvc3-add-custom-viewengine-to-new-project-dialog)

The key to getting it working on my machine (64bit) was the registry path mentioned in the answer in that post.  I also found via Reflector there is a SupportsHTML5 key too, if you need that.

Here is a screen shot of my template:
[image]

and here are the registry keys (there is also a title and description at the MyOwnTemplate node)

[image]

Comment: that's a great answer! It's so simple once you find it :)

Comment: Thnx Jason. This is exactly what I wanted. Now the only thing that is left to be done is to somehow automate this process: modify registry keys and copy .zip (template) into Project Templates folder.

Comment: Don't forget you'll need to run devenv.exe /setup to get your templates into VS's Project Template Cache.

Comment: One more thing ... If you want your template not to show also on the New Project Dialog, then you have to edit your **.vstemplate** and inside **<TemplateData>** you have to add this: **<Hidden>true</Hidden>**

Comment: Do you know of a way to specify a custom icon to display for a custom template? I've tried specifying it in the .vstemplate, but it doesn't appear that the New MVC Project dialog respects that setting.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can customize the image.  The dialog appears to use either 1 of 2 images out of a resource stored in the wizard's dll (ico9001.ico and ico9002.ico) - seems the image is triggered from the template's default language (if C# then it uses the first, otherwise it uses the second).  I don't see an easy way to plug your own in there.

Answer (score 2):

If you look up your template directory for Visual Studio, and check out the template:

MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev3.0.cs.zip

(VS Install dir)\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033

The thing to look at here is this line:

```
<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.3.0, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.UserInterface.MvcTemplateWizard</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

So they have got a custom Wizard working here.
these questions look to be similar:
[Blank Asp.net MVC template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016593/blank-asp-net-mvc-template)
[How to write an MVC3 Project Template that will offer option Razor or .aspx views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783513/how-to-write-an-mvc3-project-template-that-will-offer-option-razor-or-aspx-views)

Basically, they say the wizard isn't open source but you could potentially write your own custom wizard.

EDIT:
here are a couple of page that tell you how to create your own wizard:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/create_VS_wizard.aspx

Comment: If you use Reflector, you might want to check out these methods: code://Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.3.01:3.1.0.0:31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.UserInterface.ProjectTemplates/LoadProjectTemplate(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey,String,String):Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.UserInterface.ProjectTemplate

Comment: and code://Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.3.01:3.1.0.0:31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.UserInterface.ProjectTemplates/LoadProjectTemplates(System.IServiceProvider,String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.UserInterface.ProjectTemplate>):System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.UserInterface.ProjectTemplate>

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a blog post that covers how to do this and provides a zip file and a batch file with an example.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx

Comment: great post ... I've been waiting for this post for a while, from the day you announced that you'd write about it :D